# Need Help: Make the quiz random

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble making the questions random. If you could help, it would be awesome!

(If you have spear time; I've been given the task to mark correct answer with a green feather and wrong answers with red feather, for instance, if you get 3 correct and 2 wrong. It will show 3 green feathers and 2 red feathers as score.) Thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var questions = [
    ['firstcar.gif','0'],
    ['secondcar.gif','1'],
    ['thirdcar.gif','2'], 
    ['firstcar.gif','0'],
    ['secondcar.gif','1'],
    ['thirdcar.gif','2'] // Note: no comma after last entry
];
var qNo = 0;
var correct = 0;
var cnt = 0;

function NextQuestion(response) {
  if ((qNo < questions.length) && (response == questions[qNo][1])) { 
        correct++; 
}
  document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 'Correct ' + correct + ' of 6 questions'; 
        qNo++;

  if (qNo < questions.length) { 
    document.getElementById('Pic').src = questions[qNo][0]; 
        cnt++; 
  }else{ 
    alert('Quiz is done. You got ' + correct + ' points!'); 
  }
}

onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('Pic').src = questions[0][0];
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div align="center">
    <h1>Which car is it?</h1>
    <img src="" id="Pic" height="200" width="250">
    <p>Is it 
        <button onclick="NextQuestion('0')">Red</button>
        <button onclick="NextQuestion('1')">Black</button>
        <button onclick="NextQuestion('2')">Yellow</button> 
    <p>Your score: <br>
    <span id="score"></span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,  your questions are in an array. So what you should be researching is how to randomise the order of an array.

```
questions.sort(function() { return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); });
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm new when it comes to arrays. I'm currently learning basic jQuery.